# Does this Cuda scan kernel only work within a single block, or across multiple blocks?

Tags: cuda

I am doing a homework and have been given a Cuda kernel that performs a primitive scan operation. From what I can tell this kernel will only do a scan of the data if a single block is used (because of the `int id = threadInx.x`). Is this true?

```
//Hillis & Steele: Kernel Function
//Altered by Jake Heath, October 8, 2013 (c)
// - KD: Changed input array to be unsigned ints instead of ints
__global__ void scanKernel(unsigned int *in_data, unsigned int *out_data, size_t numElements)
{
    //we are creating an extra space for every numElement so the size of the array needs to be 2*numElements
    //cuda does not like dynamic array in shared memory so it might be necessary to explicitly state
    //the size of this mememory allocation
    __shared__ int temp[1024 * 2];

    //instantiate variables
    int id = threadIdx.x;
    int pout = 0, pin = 1;

    // // load input into shared memory. 
    // // Exclusive scan: shift right by one and set first element to 0
    temp[id] = (id > 0) ? in_data[id - 1] : 0;
    __syncthreads();


    //for each thread, loop through each of the steps
    //each step, move the next resultant addition to the thread's 
    //corresponding space to manipulted for the next iteration
    for (int offset = 1; offset < numElements; offset <<= 1)
    {
        //these switch so that data can move back and fourth between the extra spaces
        pout = 1 - pout;
        pin = 1 - pout;

        //IF: the number needs to be added to something, make sure to add those contents with the contents of 
        //the element offset number of elements away, then move it to its corresponding space
        //ELSE: the number only needs to be dropped down, simply move those contents to its corresponding space
        if (id >= offset)
        {
            //this element needs to be added to something; do that and copy it over
            temp[pout * numElements + id] = temp[pin * numElements + id] + temp[pin * numElements + id - offset];
        }
        else
        {
            //this element just drops down, so copy it over
            temp[pout * numElements + id] = temp[pin * numElements + id];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // write output
    out_data[id] = temp[pout * numElements + id];
}
```

I would like to modify this kernel to work across multiple blocks, I want it to be as simple as changing the `int id...` to `int id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x`. But the shared memory is only within the block, meaning the scan kernels across blocks cannot share the proper information.

Comment: As it stands, yes, that kernel will execute as if it were logically on a single block, since the data fetch is based *only* on `threadIdx` and not `blockIdx`. By "logically" I mean that if you were to launch several blocks of this kernel, the result would be the same as if only 1 had been launched.

Comment: So only logically. Does that mean the `__shared__` memory is grid level and not block level?

Comment: No, the `__shared__` is and always will be block level. What I meant by "logically" is that no matter the number of blocks you launch, they will all perform the same work, given the current implementation of that kernel.

Comment: So related, the call of `<<gridSz, blockSz, memSz>>` will only result in allocating block level memory of size `mem`?

Comment: It will allocate `memSz` bytes of smem for each block in the grid, in total that is `memSz * gridSz` bytes. However *all blocks* will take the same input and produce the same output, because of how `id` is computed.

Comment: @Cicada if you want to craft an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: @Robert Alright, I'll flesh something out.

Comment: Me too ^ // So if I wanted to use this kernel to scan an array of `size` > `block size`, then I would need to segment the input array into chunks of `block size - 1`. Having the last element in each scan iteration be the first element in the next iteration so that the values carry through the whole array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I can tell this kernel will only do a scan of the data if a single block is used (because of the int id = threadInx.x). Is this true?

Not exactly. This kernel will work *regardless* of how many blocks you launch, but **all blocks** will fetch the same input and compute the same output, because of how `id` is calculated:

```
int id = threadIdx.x;
```

This `id` is independant of `blockIdx`, and therefore identical across blocks, no matter their number.

---

If I were to make a multi-block version of this scan without changing too much code, I would introduce an auxilliary array to store the per-block sums. Then, run a similar scan on that array, calculating per-block increments. Finally, run a last kernel to *add* those per-block increments to the block elements. If memory serves there is a similar kernel in the CUDA SDK samples.

Since Kepler the above code could be rewritten much more efficiently, notably through the use of [`__shfl`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#warp-shuffle-functions). Additionally, changing the algorithm to work per-warp rather than per-block would get rid of the `__syncthreads` and may improve performance. A combination of both these improvements would allow you to get rid of shared memory and work only with registers for maximal performance.